# .htaccess not read on localhost xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with a .htaccess file not being read by Apache. I'm using it on my local machine, port 81. I'm using Windows 10.

I created a .htaccess file in the root directory of my .php files.
When I enter some rubbish inside .htaccess file nothing happens (website loads normally). I've checked many tutorials, threads and was unable to find a viable solution.

What I have done so far:

- Entered anything in the .htaccess file to check or the 500 error (didn't work)
- Checked the httpd.conf file for `AllowOverride All` (for directory as well)
- Re-installed Xampp

This is how my settings in httpd.conf look like now:

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
<Directory />
AllowOverride All
# Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I've got no idea what to do next. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your `root directory` also the public root?

Comment: are you sure apache is looking for `.htaccess` and not `htaccess.txt`?

Comment: The file has no name and in type it shows HTACCESS file.
As for root directory being the public root, how do I check that?

Comment: It might be that Webmatrix (software which I'm using) doesn't support .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Is this section in httpd.con like this, or is looking for any other file name?

```
#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride 
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly the same.
I tried renaming this and the .htaccess file afterwards as well but that did not work.

Comment: It might be that Webmatrix (software which I'm using) doesn't support .htaccess files.